# Search first, last name and email by one key word in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, search, text

Below you can find my code where I try to search fields (first, last name and email) in Mongoose by one key word. Unfortunately it is not working as I expected. It only returns result if full first or last name is entered, but I would like to get result in all cases:

Example:

User first and last name = John Smith

1. case: keyWord = Jo
2. case: keyWord = John
3. case: keyWord = John Sm
4. case: keyWord = John Smith
5. case: keyWord = john.smith@mail.com

Code which uses text indexes on firstName, lastName and email:

```
User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id })
      .populate({
        path: 'friends',
        select: 'firstName lastName email avatarPath facebookID',
        match: { $text: { $search: req.query.keyWord } }
      })
      .populate({
        path: 'receivedFriendRequests',
        select: 'firstName lastName email avatarPath facebookID',
        match: { $text: { $search: req.query.keyWord } }
      })
      .exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
          return res.status(500).json({
            code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
            message: config.errorCode.status500.message
          })
        }
        if (!user) {
          logger.error('Friend 404 User does not exist.')
          return res.status(404).json({
            code: config.errorCode.status404.code,
            message: config.errorCode.status404.message
          })
        }else {
          if (!user.friends) {
            logger.error('Friend 404 User friends do not exist.')
            return res.status(404).json({
              code: config.errorCode.status404.code,
              message: config.errorCode.status404.message
            })
          }
          return res.json({
            receivedFriendRequests: user.receivedFriendRequests.slice(0, 5),
            data: user.friends
          })
        }
      })
```

I also tried in this way but it is not also working for all 5 cases:

```
User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id })
      .populate({
        path: 'friends',
        select: 'firstName lastName email avatarPath facebookID',
        match: {
          $or: [
            {
              firstName: { $regex: req.query.keyWord, $options: 'i'}
            },
            {
              lastName: { $regex: req.query.keyWord, $options: 'i'}
            },
            {
              email: { $regex: req.query.keyWord, $options: 'i'}
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      .populate({
        path: 'receivedFriendRequests',
        select: 'firstName lastName email avatarPath facebookID',
        match: {
          $or: [
            {
              firstName: { $regex: req.query.keyWord, $options: 'i'}
            },
            {
              lastName: { $regex: req.query.keyWord, $options: 'i'}
            },
            {
              email: { $regex: req.query.keyWord, $options: 'i'}
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      .exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
          return res.status(500).json({
            code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
            message: config.errorCode.status500.message
          })
        }
        if (!user) {
          logger.error('Friend 404 User does not exist.')
          return res.status(404).json({
            code: config.errorCode.status404.code,
            message: config.errorCode.status404.message
          })
        }else {
          if (!user.friends) {
            logger.error('Friend 404 User friends do not exist.')
            return res.status(404).json({
              code: config.errorCode.status404.code,
              message: config.errorCode.status404.message
            })
          }
          return res.json({
            receivedFriendRequests: user.receivedFriendRequests.slice(0, 5),
            data: user.friends
          })
        }
      })
```

User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String
  },
  frstNameNormalized: {
    type: String
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String
  },
  lastNameNormalized: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    // unique: true,
    // required: true,
    lowercase: true,
  // match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please enter a valid email address']
  },
  birthDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  facebookID: {
    type: String
  },
  twitterID: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  nickname: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  avatarPath: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  friends: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  receivedFriendRequests: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  sentFriendRequests: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  sharedFriendCheckIns: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date,
  emailConfirmToken: String,
  emailConfirmExpires: Date,
  emailConfirmed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
})
....

UserSchema.index({ firstName: 'text', lastName: 'text', email: 'text'})

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there any way to implement all 5 cases?

Comment: have you found any solutions for this?

Comment: Yes, below you have solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case that someone needs it, I have resolved this problem. Since I am a beginner the solution is trivial and probably not optimal but it does what it should to.

```
FriendController.route('/').get(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function (req, res) {

var parts = (req.query.keyWord).split(' ')
var firstName = ''
var lastName = ''

if (parts.length > 1) {

  firstName = (req.query.keyWord).split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ')
  lastName = (req.query.keyWord).split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ')

} else {

  firstName = req.query.keyWord
  lastName = req.query.keyWord

}

User.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          firstName: { $regex: firstName, $options: 'i'}
        },
        {
          lastName: { $regex: lastName, $options: 'i'}
        },
        {
          email: req.query.keyWord
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      friends: req.user.id
    }
  ]
})
  .select('firstName lastName email avatarPath facebookID')
  .exec(function (err, friends) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
      return res.status(500).json({
        code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
        message: config.errorCode.status500.message
      })
    }
    User.find({
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            {
              firstName: { $regex: firstName, $options: 'i'}
            },
            {
              lastName: { $regex: lastName, $options: 'i'}
            },
            {
              email: req.query.keyWord
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          sentFriendRequests: req.user.id
        }
      ]
    })
      .select('firstName lastName email avatarPath facebookID')
      .exec(function (err, friendRequests) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
          return res.status(500).json({
            code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
            message: config.errorCode.status500.message
          })
        }
        return res.json({
          receivedFriendRequests: friendRequests,
          data: friends
        })
      })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just try and use this code I have replaced regex with $text**

```
User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id })
              .populate({
                path: 'friends',
                select: 'firstName lastName email avatarPath facebookID',
                match: 
                  { $text: { $search: req.query.keyWord } }
              })
              .populate({
                path: 'receivedFriendRequests',
                select: 'firstName lastName email avatarPath facebookID',
                match: {
                   $text: { $search: req.query.keyWord } 
                }
              })
              .exec(function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                  logger.error('Friend 500 ' + err)
                  return res.status(500).json({
                    code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
                    message: config.errorCode.status500.message
                  })
                }
                if (!user) {
                  logger.error('Friend 404 User does not exist.')
                  return res.status(404).json({
                    code: config.errorCode.status404.code,
                    message: config.errorCode.status404.message
                  })
                }else {
                  if (!user.friends) {
                    logger.error('Friend 404 User friends do not exist.')
                    return res.status(404).json({
                      code: config.errorCode.status404.code,
                      message: config.errorCode.status404.message
                    })
                  }
                  return res.json({
                    receivedFriendRequests: user.receivedFriendRequests.slice(0, 5),
                    data: user.friends
                  })
                }
              })
```

Comment: I already tried this way and it is not working for case 1 and case 3, you can see it in my first code block, but thanks anyway.